# Mechanize: Type error : Nonetype object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, mechanize

I am attempting to use Mechanize to get some data and I get the error "Nonetype object does not support item assignment". I copy the code I am using below.

```
import mechanize

url = "http://www.tropicos.org"

br = mechanize.Browser()

br.form["ct100_MainContentPlaceHolder_acNameControl_textBox"] = "poa    annua"
response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not calling `open` on `br` before you access form. Thus, try the following:

```
import mechanize

url = "http://www.tropicos.org"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url) #RIGHT HERE
br.form["ct100_MainContentPlaceHolder_acNameControl_textBox"] = "poa    annua"
response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```

And it should work.

Comment: I tried your suggesiton and still gives me the same error. I am not sure if the error comes from using the wrong search form. Python is pointing to that line of code. Any other hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add useragent and number form.

your code will look like:

```
import mechanize

useragents = [('User-agent',
           'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)')]

url = "http://www.tropicos.org"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', random.choice(useragents))]
site = br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)   
br.form["ct100_MainContentPlaceHolder_acNameControl_textBox"] = "poa    annua"
response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```

usually the select_form is set to 0
some cases its hiden